# Characterize X, such that: L(X+Y) = L(X+Z) => L(Y) = L(Z)

Tags: probability-theory

I know that if we have three independent random variables X,Y,Z then generally equality of distributions of X+Y and X+Z doesn't imply that Y and Z have the same distribution. So I am curious, is there any simple characterization of random variables X for which the implication holds? In other words: find all random variables X, such that for any Y, Z (X,Y,Z are independent) holds following implication: X+Y has the same distribution as X+Z => Y has the same distribution as Z.

Comment: Have you looked at the characteristic functions?

Comment: I see, so I guess it will be probably such random variables that have characteristic functions that are zero on a non-degenerate interval, but I can't find corresponding characteristic functions of Y,Z.